# Error in working with pyserial module of python

Tags: python, serial-port, pyserial

```
import time
import serial

# configure the serial connections (the parameters differs on the device you are connecting to)
ser = serial.Serial(
    port='/dev/ttyS0',
    #port='/dev/ttyACM0',
    baudrate=115200,
    parity=serial.PARITY_ODD,
    #stopbits=serial.STOPBITS_TWO,
    #bytesize=serial.SEVENBITS
)

ser.isOpen() # returns true 
time.sleep(1);

ser.write("some_command \n")
ser.close()
```

I have a embedded board. It has a serial port which is connected to my computer. I am running above script to access this serial port and run some board specific commands.

My problem

I open my serial port (using minicom in linux) separately and then run above script, It works. If I don't open serial port separately, Script doesn't work.

Comment: What are the chances minicom is setting different parameters than your program on the port?  It is likely your issue is about that,

Comment: No, I cross checked it. This is not the case. This is my serial port setting
Serial<id=0x7fdc62259390, open=True>(port='/dev/ttyS0', baudrate=115200, bytesize=8, parity='O', stopbits=1, timeout=None, xonxoff=False, rtscts=False, dsrdtr=False)

Comment: How does the script not work? Does it raise an exception or hang?

Comment: Its sending some junk characters. I verified it . I sent a command to set ip of my board but when I open my board (using minicom), its not set and I see some junk characters.

Comment: where is your `ser.open()`? and stop using big words like the **bug** in your titles

Comment: ser.open() gives me an error that port is already open. I have checked with ser.isOpen(), It return true. (Please check comments) So, I didn't use ser.open(). Thanks for pointing out mistake. Title is corrected.

Answer (score -1):

try

```
ser.write("some_command \n".encode())
```

alternatively try

```
ser.write(bytes(b"some_command \n"))
```